# Best practice for Azure ARM template parameters

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Getting started with ARM templates and trying to get a better understanding of what parameters go in a separate parameters file versus in the parameters section of the template itself.  Do I have to have a separate parameters file?  Seems like I can 't do a deployment from Visual Studio without identifying the parameters file.

Comment: This is a holywarish question, there can be no real answer to this

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to have a parameters file to deploy via ARM templates. You can certainly hardcode everything in your ARM template file if you like.

The next part is my opinion only on ARM template construction. I like following naming conventions for resources, such as [resource type]-[app]-[environment]. For example, a Web App for app Foo for the staging environment might be named wa-foo-prod. Following such a convention means that I can look at a resource and pretty much tell exactly what it's for.

That being said, I'm a big proponent of variables for naming resources in ARM templates. I might only pass in the environment and the region as parameters in an ARM template, then use variables to concatenate up all of the necessary resource names.

If every single resource name is passed in as a parameter, parameter management gets unwieldy.

As far as a required parameters file for deploying through VSTS, you may be right. But if you did NOT want any parameters, you could either deploy your ARM template through a Powershell script in VSTS, or just pass in an empty parameters file.

Comment: thanks for the info.  I was kinda looking for an explanation of the difference between putting parameters in the deployment json file versus putting them in the parameters file.

Comment: Ah. Since we use the same ARM template for both staging and production environments, it's best to put parameters in a parameters file. Then you can swap out the parameters file based on the environment you're provisioning.